# Post data using ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys i want to post data using ajax under `PHP` cods. Other page use this data to start a loop. so ajax hold till loop will finish this cods not working for me.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    if(!isset($token)) {
        exit;
    }
    $postid = $_POST['id'];
    $postid = str_replace(substr($postid, 0, strpos($postid, '_')) . '_', '', $postid);
    if(isset($postid)) {
        if (time()- $times['time'] < $ttime) {
            header("Location: index.php?info=TimeLimit");
        } else{
            $sql1 = "REPLACE INTO cookie (ip,time,waktu) VALUES ( '$ip','$time','$waktu')";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
            echo'<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script>  
                var postid = '.$postid.';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id:postid},
                    url: "http://example.com/example.php",
                    success: function(data){
                        //data will contain the vote count echoed by the controller i.e.  
                        "yourVoteCount"
                        //then append the result where ever you want like
                        $("span#votes_number").html(data); 
                    }
                });
            </script>';
```

Comment: what is `not working for me`?

Comment: are you doing asynchronous request? If i understood well, you need to wait the response from your call to resume your application, in that case you should make synchronous requests

Answer (score 0):

Place this in ur php file

```
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          $token = $_SESSION['token'];
          if(!isset($token)){exit;}
          $postid = $_POST['id'];
          $postid = str_replace(substr($postid, 0, strpos($postid, '_')) . '_', '', $postid);
    ?>
```

This outside php tag

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script>
      var postid = '<?php echo $postid ?>';
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/ho_likes.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {("id":postid)},
        success: function(data){
         $("span#votes_number").html(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
         alert(data);
       }
    });      
    </script>
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $token = $_SESSION['token'];
           if(!isset($token)){exit;}
 $postid = $_POST['id'];
 $postid = str_replace(substr($postid, 0, strpos($postid, '_')) . '_', '', $postid);

  ?>

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script>
      var postid = '<?php echo $postid ?>';
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/ho_likes.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {("id":postid)},
        success: function(data){
         $("span#votes_number").html(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
         alert(data);
       }
    });      
    </script>

Comment: To be very frank, this is actually a stupid code, u r passing a variable 'id' to the same page, where $postId is inside an if condition. Jus think, at first, $postid will be null. so after ajax call also the $postId inside the if condition will be null. which doesnt make any sense. Above code is jus the way how to use ajax. Follow that method. Ajax is not something to be written in an echo or else.

Comment: So Any other way to trigger this ajax cods.

Comment: I was use curl before but curl is not working on my server So i try to use ajax . Well Thanks For all help

Comment: it will posible if i add button to trigger ajax + on submit

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
  var postid = '<?php echo $postid ?>';
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/example.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "id":postid
    },
    success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
******* write code *******
});      
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttributeNode' of null

Comment: you have pass single data or multiple data??

Comment: its single data post id only

Comment: check postid not empty

Comment: try to echo id value in example.php file and print in console.log(data); show id pass or not on posted page

Comment: post is under as isset($_POST) value so maybe ajax first get empty value so cods not working. how can i trigger this by function.

Comment: try to call onclick event

Comment: Not working Hay my Curl Cods stopped working yesteryear it was working but now its not working